# Loop the halfedge_handle around a vertex

Tags: cgal

I have a vertex_handle, and what I want to do is to get the halfedge_handles around the vertex,here is my attempt:

```
HV_circulator hc = v -> vertex_begin();
  do{
    hc++;
    Polyhedron::Halfedge halfedge = *hc;
    HE_handle hh = &halfedge;

    //blabla~~
  }while(hc != v -> vertex_begin());
```

but it seems not works good, the `hh` seems not waht I want to get, 
what should I do to convert this circulator to a halfedge_hanle, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A halfedge circulator is convertible to a halfedge handle.
Thus you simply need to write:

```
Polyhedron::Halfedge_handle hh = hc;
```

Comment: I get an error conversion from ‘HV_circulator  to non-scalar type ‘HE_handle requested,HE_handle hh = hc;

Comment: It works, I reaheck the code, I encounter this error only because my HV_circulator is actully a Polyhedron::Halfedge_around_vertex_const_circulator,I delete const, and everything is fine now.

Comment: @tintin If you have a const circulator, is is convertible to a const handle: `Polyhedron::Halfedge_const_handle hh = hc;`.